# How to send a notification to my android app based on an entry in the Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an android app that uses Firebase database. The user can add events in the app by specifying a date and time. I want the user to receive a push notification when the device time and date matches with an entry in the firebase database for an event they added. It is very much like how the calendar app works to remind the user. Many solutions I have encountered involves being triggered by a **new database entry** or an **https request**. How can I implement my idea as I want an existing db entry to trigger the notification? Maybe there's another way to approach this? Thanks in advance.

--Edit--
What I am seeking is a way to schedule a notification to be sent at a particular time in the future.

Comment: You would have to use some sort of scheduling mechanism, but Firebase currently doesn't provide anything like that.

Comment: @DougStevenson That's what I thought. Is there any other service that could help me schedule a notification?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloud Functions for Firebase to trigger arbitrary code to run when that field is updated. Then you'll have to check if it matches the desired value before sending the notification. Loosely based off [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js), you could check if the date matches before running the notification. Now this is just an example and not complete, but hopefully it helps get the idea across.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/user/{uid}/dates/{date}')
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    const desiredDate = await admin.database().ref('desiredDate').get(); // get the desired date you want to match
    const date = context.params.date;
    if (date != desiredDate.val()) {
        return null; // or whatever you want to do to exit program
    }
    // code to send message here
}
```

Comment: I believe this isn't scalable. Moreover, I require the notification to be scheduled to be sent at a time specified by the user (not only the date).

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought you meant you wanted notifications to go out when a user created an event if the date they specified matched.